# Copy the specific files listed in text file from source folder to Destination folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of file names in a text file with different format. I have multiple files found in the Source folder , I like to search files in the source folder with respective file name in text file copy those file and paste it to destination folder.

Example :

Text File : contains only limited (Selected files)

```
C:/.../abc.doc::1
C:/.../def.doc::1
c:/.../ghu.doc::1
c:/.../zzz.doc::1
```

Source Folder :

```
C:/.../abc.doc
C./.../12a.doc
C:/.../def.doc
c:/.../ghu.doc
c:/.../zzz.doc
```

Destination Folder :

```
C:/.../abc.doc
C:/.../def.doc
c:/.../ghu.doc
c:/.../zzz.doc
```

I am new to python , I tried my level best, need some valuable input to finish my home work

```
Step1: I like to select the text file
Step2: Slice the line only the file name (C:/.../abc.doc::1) to file name(abc) 
Step3: Search the file name in the source folder
Step4: Copy and paste it to destination folder.
```

Code :

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#FolderA = os.path.normpath(filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/", title="Select png source path")) + "\\"
text_file_list =  os.path.normpath(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title="Select Rating text or csv file", filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"), ("all files","*.*"))))
FolderB = os.path.normpath(filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/", title="Select png source path")) + "\\"
print (FolderA)
print (FolderB)

os.chdir(text_file_list)

namelist = list()

for f in os.listdir():
    file_name,file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    namelist.append(file_name)

os.chdir(FolderB)

for findex, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    t = f
    strs.startswith('py') and strs.endswith("27")
    file_name,file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    os.rename(f, namelist[findex] + file_ext)
    print(file_name)
```

> Copy from comment:

```
with open(text_file_list, "r") as ins: 
    array = [] 
    for line in ins: 
        array.append(line) 
        print(line) 
        m = re.search(r"(?<=tinted_combined).*?(?=.jpg::1)", your_text).group(0) 
        if m: 
            found = m.group(1) 
            print(found)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Where in the code are you stuck?

Comment: I wrote the code where i can copy and paste , But I want to slice the filename oly

Comment: @Dian19007: You can't use `.askopenfilename(...` and do with the result `os.chdir(text_file_list)`. I see no attemp to fulfill *"Step2:"*?

Comment: @Dian19007: Using `re` for a simple `Step2: Slice ...` is overkill. Read [6.3.3. Slicings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-42) and [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Hope it works.

```
import os
import shutils

files = [os.path.join(SOURCE_PATH, f) for f in os.listdir(SOURCE_PATH)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(SOURCE_PATH, f))]
for file in files:
    shutil.move(file, DESTINATION_PATH)
```